# Unable to edit width of an android View programmatically before displaying

Tags: android

I am trying to edit the width of a TextView before it is getting loaded on the screen based on some score value. The requirement is like, based on the relative score value the text view should have width.

I have written the below code in onCreate() method of the activity as below,

{{{

```
TextView graph = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.predictionScoreGraph);

    graph.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int score = 60;

                    UserData data = UserData.getInstance();
                    score = data.overallScore();
                    TextView graph = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.predictionScoreGraph);

                    int grossWidth = graph.getWidth();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Existing width of the text view is "
                            + grossWidth);

                    LayoutParams existing = graph.getLayoutParams();
                    int fillWidth = (grossWidth * score) / 100;

                    Log.d(TAG, "Modified width is " + fillWidth);
                    graph.setWidth(fillWidth);
                    existing.width = fillWidth;
                    graph.setLayoutParams(existing);
                    graph.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                            android.R.color.holo_green_light));


                    graph.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                }
            });
```

}}}

It works like a Gem!! But when I want to do it for more than one TextView objects, it is not changing the width of the TextView object.

Can somebody please help me on how to change width of multiple TextView objects?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a `GlobalLayoutListener`, try overriding the `onMeasure` method of the Activity.